# QuickFIX Initiator can't send message

Tags: c++, quickfix

I've been trying to use QuickFIX to setup a client. It's the example from the QuickFIX site, as follows:

```
int main( int argc, char** argv ) {
  try
  {
    if(argc < 2) return 1;
    std::string fileName = argv[1];
    FIX::SessionSettings settings(fileName);
    Handler application;
    FIX::FileStoreFactory storeFactory(settings);
    FIX::FileLogFactory logFactory(settings);
    FIX::SocketInitiator initiator(application, storeFactory, settings, logFactory /*optional*/);
    initiator.start();
    cout << "Started.\n";
    initiator.block();
    cout << "Stopped.\n";
    return 0;
  }
  catch(FIX::ConfigError& e)
  {
    std::cout << e.what();
    return 1;
  }
}
```

And I defined the `Handler` implementing the `Application` class. 
And the config file looks like below:

```
# default settings for sessions
[DEFAULT]
ConnectionType=initiator
ReconnectInterval=60
SenderCompID=CLIENT
FileLogPath=.
FileStorePath=.
DataDictionary=D:\Program Files\quickfix\spec\FIX44.xml

# session definition
[SESSION]
# inherit ConnectionType, ReconnectInterval and SenderCompID from default
BeginString=FIX.4.4
TargetCompID=SERVER
HeartBtInt=30
SocketConnectPort=6523
SocketConnectHost=127.0.0.1
StartTime=8:00:00
EndTime=23:00:00
```

When running, the `Handler::toAdmin` and `Handler::onCreate` got called, then the `block` function blocks. But using the small FIX application Mini-FIX as the server, I could not get any incoming message from the program. I have tried opening two Mini-FIX, one as a server, one as a client, and they communicate just fine. And I have made sure that the ID's and listening port are correct. So what would be the problem? Mini-FIX should have received the `toAdmin` Message `8=FIX.4.4|9=55|35=5|34=1|49=CLIENT|52=20120702-08:29:25.334|56=SERVER|10=115` sent by the program.
Tthe start time and endtime seems strange, but the `toAdmin` actually got called. So I assume the message should have already sent.

**Edit**
 I solved the problem already after I made several changes to the config file and the program, but I am not quite sure what caused it. Consider this closed.

Comment: what seems strange about the start and end times?

Comment: @MD-Tech I assume that the initiator will be started when the time is inbetween the `starttime` and the `endtime`. But it seems that the `toAdmin` only got called when time is outside of the range of `starttime` and `endtime`. .All using UTC time.

Comment: To use UTC time, you must put this line in the config file: UseLocalTime=N

Comment: @stexcec I've tried the option before. Both `Y` and `N` do not work as expected. Anyway, it is irrelevant to the problem here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has gone, after I manipulated the config file and the Mini-FIX.
It seems that it was caused by several reasons:

1. The time should be set in the interval.
2. Mini-FIX which acts as server should set the targetcomputerid correctly.
3. `initiator.block()` is enough for starting the engine and waiting. No need to run `start()` and `block()` both.

Answer (score 2):

The FIX message you post in your question is a LOGOUT message (35=5), and it's very strange to initiate the connection with this kind of message. I expect that the first message is a LOGON (35=A). Try to reset the sequence numbers at every logon, adding this line in the config:

```
ResetOnLogon=Y
```

Also in the QuickFIX distribution there is a small server (executor) that you can use to test your client. Please find the server here:

http://www.quickfixengine.org/quickfix/doc/html/examples.html

Comment: Thanks. The Logout message seems to be result from not in the trade time. I solved the problem already after I made several changes to the config file and the program, but I am not quite sure what caused it.